# ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found

Tags: log4j2

ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console. Set system property 'org.apache.logging.log4j.simplelog.StatusLogger.level' to TRACE to show Log4j2 internal initialization logging.

solution this problem :

1.add log4j2.xml

2.add content

```
<Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1}:%L - %msg%n" />
    </Console>

    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" filename="log/rolling.log"
                 filepattern="${logPath}/%d{YYYYMMddHHmmss}-rolling.log">
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1}:%L - %msg%n" />
        <Policies>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="100 MB" />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="20" />
    </RollingFile>

</Appenders>
<Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile" />
    </Root>
    <Logger name="corg.springframework.web" level="INFO">
        <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
    </Logger>
</Loggers>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration looks mostly correct but needs to be encapsulated in a `<Configuration>` element. See the many examples in the Log4j2 user manual.

Comment: yeah,i konw it, There's no replication all code,thanks